# Change TTL for subdomain records in Windows Server DNS with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, dns

I am trying to bulk edit DNS TTL in Windows Server DNS using PowerShell.
What I really can't wrap my head around is the absence of any FQDN in Record Objects I get from `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord`.

My DNS setup has a primary zone and many subdomains.

```
primaryzone.tld
├── sub1
│  ├── record1
│  ├── record2
│  └── subsub1
│     ├── (same as parent)
│     ├── record1.1
│     └── record2.1
├── sub2
└── sub3
```

As there is no possibility to recurse with `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord` I have to loop over the subdomains, which I can not gather programatically, to get all records, not just the ones on the root-level of the zone:

```
$DNSServer = "dc.company.tld"
$Zone = "primaryzone.tld"
$ChildZone = "sub1"
$SubDomains = @("","subsub1")
ForEach ($SubDomain in $SubDomains){
    if ( $SubDomain -ne "" ) {
        $FullDomain = "$($SubDomain).$($ChildZone)"
    }
    else {
        $FullDomain = $ChildZone
    } 
    Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSServer -ZoneName $Zone -Name "$($FullDomain)"
```

Is this really supposed to be that way?

If I now want to change TTL for all records under `subsub1` I try it like this:

```
 Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSServer -ZoneName $Zone -Name "$($FullDomain)"  |
    ForEach-Object{
            $newRecord = $_.Clone()
            $newRecord.TimeToLive = $ttl
            Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSServer -NewInputObject $newRecord -OldInputObject $_ -ZoneName $Zone
    }
```

Which works for the `subsub1 (same as parent)` record, that has a `HostName` property of `subsub1.sub1` thus giving a full path inside the `primaryzone.tld`. Whereas the `record1.1` has a `HostName` of `record1.1` stripping it of any information regarding its position in the tree. This results in this error:

```
Set-DnsServerResourceRecord : Resource record in OldInputObject not found in primaryzone.tld zone on dc.company.tld server.
At C:\Users\me\Desktop\dns_ttl.ps1:24 char:13
+             Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSServer -NewInputObject ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dc.company.tld:root/Microsoft/...rResourceRecord) [Set-DnsServerResourceRecord], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WIN32 9714,Set-DnsServerResourceRecord
```

I interpret this as the `Set-DnsServerResourceRecord` not finding the `OldInputObject` record because it has no clue where to look, except in the root-level of the zone.

Why can I specify `-Name subdomain` for `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord` but when writing it back with `Set-DnsServerResourceRecord` it does not take a `-Name` argument?
Why don't record objects not contain any info on their absolute (FQDN) position in the zone?

How can something so simple be so hard?

**EDIT:**

I changed my script according to the suggestions by @Cpt.Whale

```
$DNSServer = "dc.company.tld"
$TargetZone = "primary.tld"
$TTL = [System.TimeSpan]::FromMinutes(1)
$SubDomain = "sub.primary.tld" 

$Zones = Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName $DNSServer | Where {
    $_.ZoneType -eq 'Primary' -and 
    $_.IsReverseLookupZone -eq $false -and
    $_.ZoneName -ne 'TrustAnchors' -and
    $_.ZoneName -eq $TargetZone
}


Foreach ($DnsZone in $Zones) {
  # Get all records in zone by not specifying -Name:
  $Records = $DnsZone | Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSServer
  $Records | Foreach { 
    if ($_.HostName -match "$SubDomain$") {
        if ($_.TimeToLive -ne $TTL) {
            # This weird copy is due to awkward CIM references
            $oldRecord = $_
            $newRecord = $_.Clone()
            $newRecord.TimeToLive = $TTL

            # Update the TTL on the existing record:
            Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSServer -Old $oldRecord -New $newRecord -ZoneName $DnsZone.ZoneName
            # Report changes
            "{0,-50} TTL changed from {1,12} to {2,12}" -f $_.HostName, $_.TimeToLive, $TTL
        }
     }
  }
}
```

With this I get full `HostName`, but still the Error I described above

Answer (score 0):

the DNS record-type cim object doesn't have a `ZoneName` property, but it does keep the subdomain - it's part of the `HostName` of the record. DNS barely cares about subdomains at all unless they are a separate zone.

Something to start with is double-checking whether you've actually got only one zone:

```
$zones = Get-DnsServerZone -ComputerName $DNSServer | Where {
    $_.ZoneType -eq 'Primary' -and 
    $_.IsReverseLookupZone -eq $false -and
    $_.ZoneName -ne 'TrustAnchors'
}
$zones
```

Then, for example:

```
$TTL = [System.TimeSpan]::FromHours(2)  ## example TTL

Foreach ($DnsZone in $Zones) {
  # Get all records in zone by not specifying -Name:
  $records = $DnsZone | Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSServer
  $records | Foreach { 
    # This weird copy is due to awkward CIM references
    $old = $_
    $new = $_.Clone()
      $new.TimeToLive = $TTL
    # Update the TTL on the existing record:
    Set-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $DNSServer -Old $old -New $new -ZoneName $DnsZone.ZoneName
  }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple zones, but want to change the TTL only for a specific subdomain of one zone, not for all records in all zones. That's why I want to pass `-Name` to `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord`.
Also, the record itself does not keep the subdomain as part of the `HostName`, as I explained in my original post. This is what confuses me the most. When exporting the whole zone to `bind` format the Hostnames have the respective subdomain appended, as I would expect. But not when using `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord`.